# During xml parsing does not convert & to &amp; ? What can be the best solution for this?

Tags: java, xml

I want my response with & only instead of `&amp;` in xml format .I know it's control character which automatically convert but can be possible it remains as it is. What will be the solution?

Comment: During what XML parsing? The parser should see `&amp;` in the XML source, and deliver the un-escaped character. Not the other way round.

Comment: `&` alone is not allowed in XML; use `&amp;` instead.   If `&` appears outside of CDATA other than as part of a character entity such as `&amp;`, `&lt;`, etc, then the data is not XML.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep control character inside CDATA.
Please refer here - [What does <![CDATA[]]> in XML mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean)

Comment: public String xmlCdata(Object source, Class<?> type) {
  Document doc=null;
  DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setValidating(true);
        factory.setExpandEntityReferences(false);
        try {
   doc =factory.newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
  } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
        return doc.createCDATASection((String) source).getWholeText(); 
 }

Comment: I tried above code but it's not working.Please tell me what's wrong in this and what will be the correct syntax for CDATA in java?

Comment: Please follow the example given here - https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=org.w3c.dom.Document&method=createCDATASection